# drawPolyLine() vs drawLine() when plotting/graphing mathematical functions

Tags: java, swing, plot, graph, paint

I programmed a small program, that plots a mathematical function and gives the root of the function (Nullstelle/n) and the extreme points (Extrempunkte) and if there are any the discontinuity of a function(but only if the discontinuity is a number less exact than five decimal places). This all works, but the graph itself doesn't look that good. I used `Graphics2D.Line2DDouble`

```
for(int o =0; o<AnzahlanFunktionen;o++) {
                    
                    //Funktionsgraphen
                    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2)); 
                    int Genauigkeit = 1000;
                    ArrayList<Double> xcoords = new ArrayList<Double>();
                    ArrayList<Double> ycoords = new ArrayList<Double>();
                    
                    for(int x3 = (-16*Genauigkeit); x3<(16*Genauigkeit)+1; x3++) {
                        //Da x sehr groß ist und somit nicht bei der Zeichnung der Funktion eingesetzt werden kann, verwendete ich x2
                        double x2 = x3/(Genauigkeit/1.0);
                        xcoords.add(x2);
                        x.setArgumentValue(x2);
                        //y2 ist die Funktion
                        switch(o) {
                        case 0:
                            ycoords.add(fx1.getArgumentValue());
                            y = fx1.getArgumentValue();
                            g2d.setColor(new Color(200,35,35));
                            g.drawString("f(x) = "+text2.getText(),60,100);
                            break;
                        case 1: 
                            ycoords.add(fx2.getArgumentValue());
                            y = fx2.getArgumentValue();
                            g2d.setColor(new Color(55,43,156));
                            g.drawString("f(x) = "+text.getText(),60,120);
                            break;
                        case 2: 
                            ycoords.add(fx3.getArgumentValue());
                            y = fx3.getArgumentValue();
                            g2d.setColor(new Color(210,233,57));
                            g.drawString("f(x) = "+text3.getText(),60,140);
                            break;
                        case 3: 
                            ycoords.add(fx4.getArgumentValue());
                            y = fx4.getArgumentValue();
                            g2d.setColor(new Color(26,151,7));
                            g.drawString("f(x) = "+text4.getText(),60,160);
                            break;      
                        }
                        
                        

                        //Diese Zeile zeichnet den Graphen 
                        if(!(Double.isNaN(y))) g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(Main.breite/2+x2*(Main.höhe/20), Main.höhe/2-y*(Main.höhe/20),Main.breite/2+x2*(Main.höhe/20), Main.höhe/2-y*(Main.höhe/20)));
                        
                    }
```

UI:
[image]

Plotting of the graphs:

[image]

If I used `drawPolyLine`, would I get a more detailed and less "bricky" graph? Does it even make a difference? Is there another way to draw the graph, that looks better or is more efficiently?

Entire Code for those interested:

```
package graphikrechner.com;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4648172894076113183L;
    private static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    public static double breite = screenSize.getWidth();
    public static double höhe = screenSize.getHeight();
    
    public Main() {
    
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Graphikrechner by Visar Lumi");
        f.setSize(new Dimension((int)breite,(int)höhe));
        f.setMaximumSize(new Dimension((int)breite,(int)höhe));
        f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension((int)breite,(int)höhe));
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)breite,(int)höhe));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setAlwaysOnTop (true);
        f.add(new GUI());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }

        });
        
        
        

    }

}

package graphikrechner.com;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.Argument;

public class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7365905689502130889L;
    private JTextField text = new JTextField(20);
    private JTextField text2 = new JTextField(20);
    private JTextField text3 = new JTextField(20);
    private JTextField text4 = new JTextField(20);
    
    private JButton button,button2,plusbutton,minusbutton;
    private boolean FalscheEingabe = false;
    private int AnzahlanFunktionen = 1;
    private double y,z3;
    
    private static String Error,number;
    private static BigDecimal a;
    private Argument x,fx1,fx2,fx3,fx4;
    
    public static int GUI = 1;
    
    
    
    
    public void createGUI() {
        //Fonts
        Font BigFont = new Font("Roboto",Font.BOLD,55);
        Font RegularFont = new Font("Roboto",Font.BOLD,24);
        Font TextFont = new Font("Latin Modern",Font.PLAIN,19);
        
        Icon buttonImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("button_okay-_1_.jpg"));
        Icon plusbuttonImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("button-_1_.jpeg"));
        Icon minusbuttonImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("button-_2_.jpg"));
        
        setLayout(null);
        
        text.setBounds((int) Main.breite/2 , (int) Main.höhe/2 + 2,240,30);
        text.setFont(TextFont);
        
        text2.setBounds((int) Main.breite/2 , (int) Main.höhe/2 + 2 + 35,240,30);
        text2.setFont(TextFont);
        
        text3.setBounds((int) Main.breite/2 , (int) Main.höhe/2 + 2 + 35*2,240,30);
        text3.setFont(TextFont);
        
        text4.setBounds((int) Main.breite/2 , (int) Main.höhe/2 + 2 + 35*3,240,30);
        text4.setFont(TextFont);
        
        switch(AnzahlanFunktionen) {
        case 1:
            this.add(text); 
            break;
        case 2:
            this.add(text);
            this.add(text2);
            break;
        case 3:
            this.add(text);
            this.add(text2);
            this.add(text3);
            break;
        case 4:
            this.add(text);
            this.add(text2);
            this.add(text3);
            this.add(text4);
            break;
        }
        if(AnzahlanFunktionen > 1) {
            minusbutton = new JButton(minusbuttonImage);
            minusbutton.setBounds((int) Main.breite/2 +245, (int) Main.höhe/2 + 2,40,30);
            minusbutton.addActionListener(this);
            this.add(minusbutton);
        }
        if(AnzahlanFunktionen != 4){
            plusbutton = new JButton(plusbuttonImage);
            plusbutton.setBounds((int) Main.breite/2 +245, (int) Main.höhe/2 + 2 + 35*(AnzahlanFunktionen-1),40,30);
            plusbutton.addActionListener(this);
            this.add(plusbutton);
        }
        
        
        button = new JButton(buttonImage);
        button.setBounds((int) Main.breite/2 + 40 , (int) Main.höhe/2 + 40 + + 2 + 35*(AnzahlanFunktionen-1),167,40);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setToolTipText("Funktion eingeben");
        this.add(button);
        
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Gib eine Funktion ein:");
        label.setFont(RegularFont);
        label.setBounds(420, (int) Main.höhe/2 -10 ,500,50);
        this.add(label);
        
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Graphikrechner");
        label2.setFont(BigFont);
        label2.setForeground(new Color(60,147,205));
        label2.setBounds(475,100,1000,70);
        this.add(label2);
        
        
        if(FalscheEingabe) {
            JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Error-Funktion nicht vorhanden oder falsch eingegeben");
            label3.setFont(new Font("Roboto",Font.BOLD,15));
            label3.setForeground(Color.red);
            label3.setBounds(500, (int) Main.höhe - 250 + 32*(AnzahlanFunktionen-1),1000,20);
            this.add(label3);
        }
    }
    
    public void createButton() {
        Icon buttonImage2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("button_go-back_1.jpg"));
        setLayout(null);
        button2 = new JButton(buttonImage2);
        button2.setBounds(0,0,167,48);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(button2);
    }
    
    public GUI() {
        
        
        if(GUI == 1) createGUI();
        
       
            
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
         
        if(GUI == 0) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            x = new Argument("x");
            fx1 = new Argument("y ="+text.getText(),x);
            fx2 = new Argument("y ="+text2.getText(),x);
            fx3 = new Argument("y ="+text3.getText(),x);
            fx4 = new Argument("y ="+text4.getText(),x);
            
            //Die nächsten Zeile überprüfen ob die eingegebene Funktion richtig geschrieben wurde (z.B 3x => Error => FalscheEingabe=true; 3*x => no errors => FalscheEingabe=>false) 
            
            
            for(int i = 0; i<AnzahlanFunktionen; i++) {
                switch(i) {
                case 0:
                    fx1.checkSyntax();
                    Error = fx1.getErrorMessage();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fx2.checkSyntax();
                    Error = fx2.getErrorMessage();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fx3.checkSyntax();
                    Error = fx3.getErrorMessage();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fx4.checkSyntax();
                    Error = fx4.getErrorMessage();
                    break;
                    
                }
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(Error);
                int counter = 0;
                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String token = st.nextToken();
                 
                    if(counter == 0 && !(token.equals("no"))) {
                        FalscheEingabe = true;      
                        counter = 1;
                    }
                    else if (counter==1 && token.equals("no")) FalscheEingabe = false;
                }
                if(FalscheEingabe) i=AnzahlanFunktionen;
            }
            if(FalscheEingabe) {
                GUI = 1;
                text.setText("");
                text2.setText("");
                text3.setText("");
                text4.setText("");
                createGUI();
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
            
            if(GUI == 0) {
                createButton();
                g.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",Font.BOLD,25));
                
                //KoordinatenSystem und Graphen
        
                //x-Achse
                Polygon dreieck = new Polygon();
                dreieck.addPoint((int)Main.breite/2, 0);
                dreieck.addPoint(((int)Main.breite/2)-60,40);
                dreieck.addPoint(((int)Main.breite/2)+60,40);
                g2d.setColor(Color.black);
                g2d.fill(dreieck);
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawLine((int)Main.breite/2, 42, (int)Main.breite/2,(int) Main.höhe);
        
                //y-Achse
                Polygon dreieck2 = new Polygon();
                dreieck2.addPoint((int)Main.breite -15,(int)Main.höhe/2);
                dreieck2.addPoint((int)Main.breite -60,(int)Main.höhe/2 -60);
                dreieck2.addPoint((int)Main.breite -60,(int)Main.höhe/2 +60);
                g2d.fill(dreieck2);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawLine(0, (int) Main.höhe/2, (int)Main.breite-42,(int) Main.höhe/2);
        
        
                //Nummerierung
                //x-Achse
                int xKoordinaten = 9;
                for(int i = (int) (Main.höhe/20); i<(int) (Main.höhe*19/20); i+=(int)Main.höhe/20) {
                    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
                    g.drawLine((int)Main.breite/2+10,i+3,(int)Main.breite/2-10,i+3);
                    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
                    g.drawLine(0, i+3, (int)Main.breite, i+3);
                    if(xKoordinaten != 0) {
                        g.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",Font.BOLD,20));
                        g.drawString(""+xKoordinaten, (int)Main.breite/2-43, i+10);
                    }
                    xKoordinaten -= 1;
        
                }
                //y-Achse positiv
                int yKoordinaten = 0;
                for(int i = (int) Main.breite/2+3; i<(int) Main.breite-40; i+=(int)Main.höhe/20) {
                    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
                    g.drawLine(i-3,(int)Main.höhe/2+10,i-3,(int)Main.höhe/2-10);
                    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
                    g.drawLine(i-3, 0, i-3, (int)Main.höhe);
                    if(yKoordinaten != 0) {
                        g.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",Font.BOLD,20));
                        g.drawString(""+yKoordinaten, i-7, (int) Main.höhe/2+39);
                    }
                    yKoordinaten += 1;
        
                }
                //y-Achse negativ
                int yminusKoordinaten = 0;
                for(int i = (int) Main.breite/2+3; i>40; i-=(int)Main.höhe/20) {
                    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
                    g.drawLine(i-3,(int)Main.höhe/2+10,i-3,(int)Main.höhe/2-10);
                    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
                    g.drawLine(i-3,0,i-3,(int)Main.höhe);
                    if(yminusKoordinaten != 0 && yminusKoordinaten != -1) {
                        g.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",Font.BOLD,20));
                        g.drawString(""+yminusKoordinaten, i-7, (int) Main.höhe/2+39);
                    }
                    yminusKoordinaten -= 1;
        
                }
                int counter2 = 1;
                //Zeichnung und Nullstellenbestimmungen aller eingegebenen Funktionen
                for(int o =0; o<AnzahlanFunktionen;o++) {
                    
                    //Funktionsgraphen
                    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2)); 
                    int Genauigkeit = 1000;
                    ArrayList<Double> xcoords = new ArrayList<Double>();
                    ArrayList<Double> ycoords = new ArrayList<Double>();
                    
                    for(int x3 = (-16*Genauigkeit); x3<(16*Genauigkeit)+1; x3++) {
                        //Da x sehr groß ist und somit nicht bei der Zeichnung der Funktion eingesetzt werden kann, verwendete ich x2
                        double x2 = x3/(Genauigkeit/1.0);
                        xcoords.add(x2);
                        x.setArgumentValue(x2);
                        //y2 ist die Funktion
                        switch(o) {
                        case 0:
                            ycoords.add(fx1.getArgumentValue());
                            y = fx1.getArgumentValue();
                            g2d.setColor(new Color(200,35,35));
                            g.drawString("f(x) = "+text2.getText(),60,100);
                            break;
                        case 1: 
                            ycoords.add(fx2.getArgumentValue());
                            y = fx2.getArgumentValue();
                            g2d.setColor(new Color(55,43,156));
                            g.drawString("f(x) = "+text.getText(),60,120);
                            break;
                        case 2: 
                            ycoords.add(fx3.getArgumentValue());
                            y = fx3.getArgumentValue();
                            g2d.setColor(new Color(210,233,57));
                            g.drawString("f(x) = "+text3.getText(),60,140);
                            break;
                        case 3: 
                            ycoords.add(fx4.getArgumentValue());
                            y = fx4.getArgumentValue();
                            g2d.setColor(new Color(26,151,7));
                            g.drawString("f(x) = "+text4.getText(),60,160);
                            break;      
                        }
                        
                        

                        //Diese Zeile zeichnet den Graphen 
                        if(!(Double.isNaN(y))) g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(Main.breite/2+x2*(Main.höhe/20), Main.höhe/2-y*(Main.höhe/20),Main.breite/2+x2*(Main.höhe/20), Main.höhe/2-y*(Main.höhe/20)));
                        
                    }
                    //Nullstellenbestimmung
                    int phase = 0;
                    double z4 = 0;
                    g.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",Font.BOLD,20));
                    for(int i=0; i<ycoords.size(); i++) {
                        if(i<(ycoords.size()-1)) {
                            double z = Math.abs(ycoords.get(i+1));
                            double z2 = Math.abs(ycoords.get(i));
                            //Die nächsten paar Zeile sorgen dafür, dass er bei rationalen Funktionen die richtigen Nst oder Extrempunkte erkennt
                            if(i>1) z4 = Math.abs(ycoords.get(i-1));
                            
                            
                            if(Double.isNaN(z4))  {
                                
                                if(!(Double.isInfinite(z2)) && !(Double.isNaN(z2))) {
                                    if(phase == 0) phase = 1;
                                    else phase = 0;
                                    g.drawString("Definitionslücke bei:"+ xcoords.get(i-1),800,counter2*50);
                                    counter2++;
                                }
                            }
                            if(phase == 0 && !(Double.isNaN(z)) && !(Double.isNaN(z2)) && !(Double.isInfinite(z)) && !(Double.isInfinite(z2))) {
                                
                                if(z>z2) {
                                        if(i==0) {
                                            //Damit er nicht bei exponentiallen Funktionen denkt, dass diese Nullstellen besitzen
                                            x.setArgumentValue(-1*((ycoords.size()/2)+1));
                                            switch(o) {
                                            case 0:
                                                fx1.getArgumentValue();
                                                break;
                                            case 1:
                                                fx2.getArgumentValue();
                                                break;
                                            case 2:
                                                fx3.getArgumentValue();
                                                break;
                                            case 3:
                                                fx4.getArgumentValue();
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            if(z3>z2)  {
                                            
                                                //Er findet die Anzahl an nachkommastellen heraus
                                                number = Double.toString(z2);
                                                a = new BigDecimal(number);
                                                //Und rundet den Wert je nach Anzahl ab und wenn dieser 0 entspricht => Nullstelle sonst => Extrempunkt
                                                if((Math.round(z2*10*a.scale())/(10*a.scale()/1.0)) == 0) {
                                                    g.drawString("Nullstelle bei: ("+xcoords.get(i)+"/"+Math.round(z2*10*a.scale())/(10*a.scale()/1.0)+")",800,counter2*50);
                                                    counter2++;
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    if(!(Double.isNaN(z4))) {
                                                        g.drawString("Extrempunkt bei: ("+xcoords.get(i)+"/"+Math.round(z2*10*a.scale())/(10*a.scale()/1.0)+")",800,counter2*50);
                                                        counter2++;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                
                                            }                                   
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            //Er findet die Anzahl an nachkommastellen heraus
                                            number = Double.toString(z2);
                                            a = new BigDecimal(number);
                                            //Und rundet den Wert je nach Anzahl ab und wenn dieser 0 entspricht => Nullstelle sonst => Extrempunkt
                                            if((Math.round(z2*10*a.scale())/(10*a.scale()/1.0)) == 0) {
                                                g.drawString("Nullstelle bei: ("+xcoords.get(i)+"/"+Math.round(z2*10*a.scale())/(10*a.scale()/1.0)+")",800,counter2*50);
                                                counter2++;
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                if(!(Double.isNaN(z4))) {
                                                    g.drawString("Extrempunkt bei: ("+xcoords.get(i)+"/"+Math.round(z2*10*a.scale())/(10*a.scale()/1.0)+")",800,counter2*50);
                                                    counter2++;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        phase = 1;
                                        
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            else if(phase == 1 && !(Double.isNaN(z)) && !(Double.isNaN(z2)) && !(Double.isInfinite(z)) && !(Double.isInfinite(z2))){
                                
                                if(z < z2 ) {
                                        phase = 0;
                                        //Er findet die Anzahl an nachkommastellen heraus
                                        
                                        number = Double.toString(z2);
                                        a = new BigDecimal(number);
                                        
                                        
                                        //Und rundet den Wert je nach Anzahl ab und wenn dieser 0 entspricht => Nullstelle sonst => Extrempunkt
                                        if((Math.round(z2*10*a.scale())/(10*a.scale()/1.0)) == 0) {
                                            g.drawString("Nullstelle bei: ("+xcoords.get(i)+"/"+Math.round(z2*10*a.scale())/(10*a.scale()/1.0)+")",800,counter2*50);
                                            counter2++;
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            if(!(Double.isNaN(z4))) {
                                                g.drawString("Extrempunkt bei: ("+xcoords.get(i)+"/"+Math.round(z2*10*a.scale())/(10*a.scale()/1.0)+")",800,counter2*50);
                                                counter2++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                        
                                }
                            }
                        }
    
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        else if(GUI == 1) {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0,0,(int)Main.breite,(int)Main.höhe);
        }
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        if(e.getSource() == button) {
                GUI = 0;
                removeAll();
                revalidate();
                repaint();
                
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == button2) {
            removeAll();
            GUI = 1;
            text.setText("");
            text2.setText("");
            createGUI();
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == plusbutton && AnzahlanFunktionen != 4) {
            removeAll();
            AnzahlanFunktionen++;
            createGUI();
            revalidate();
            repaint();
            
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == minusbutton) {
            removeAll();
            AnzahlanFunktionen--;
            createGUI();
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

If you want to try it out: https://www.transfernow.net/pQO5J9062020

Comment: Try to add `g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);`.

Comment: Where is the `Argument` class? Please update you code to be a [minimal reproducibleexamle](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You need to download mxparser to access the Argument and the Function classes. Link:https://mathparser.org/mxparser-downloads/

Comment: @weisj Can I ask why I should add 
 `g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)?`

Comment: OR: You can just remove everything except for the `for(int x3=-16*Genauigkeit;x3<16*Genauigkeit;x3++)`and instead of `x.setArgumentValue()`  and `y.setArgumentValue()` , use x2 and y. Then set y as a function: y= Math.sin(x2); And then just draw it with the Line2DDouble

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are drawing the graph using `g.draw(new Line(...)` where the start and end point of the line are the same. This will result in undesired behaviour.
Instead you should paint lines between the last point of the graph and the current point of the graph. The easiest way to achieve this is by using a `Path2D`. `Path2D` is essentially a more general version of `Line2D`. First you move the path to its initial position using `moveTo()` and then each call of `lineTo()` will add a line from the current position to the new specified position and updates the current position to the new one. In contrast to drawing each line by itself (which also requires to manually remember the last point) `Path2D` may do some paint optimisations to reduce sharp edges where the lines join.

Additionally setting `g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)` will tell swing to "smooth out" the stuff it is drawing. See [Antialiasing](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antialiasing_(Computergrafik)).

Here is a sample implementation of how to draw a sine curve. Notice how coordinates are translated from "screen space" to "axis space" and back. The screen space represent coordinates in the panel (the screen). Axis space however represents the coordinate relative to the coordinate axis you want to visualise. By doing this your function will always be in the same range regardless of how big your window is. For example here the visible coordinate axis will always go from `x=-2*pi` to `x=2*pi` and `y=-1.5` to `y=1.5`.

`screenToAxis` and `axisToScreen` allow for easier abstractions between your screen size and what part of the coordinate axis you actually want to display.
Depending on the function you want to plot these bounds may vary. By abstracting you only need to adjust the axis sizes and offsets without having to rewrite the paint method.

Note that your code already does something similar only with very hard coded values und missing clarity of what is happening. The part where you are calculating `x2` because `"x3 is too large"` is exactly doing the same thing but mixing the screen to axis calculation with the precision calculation into one. The same thing applies for when you do the transformation back from `x2,y` to the point you are drawing on the screen.

Depending on the graph you are trying to paint you might need to adjust the value of `precisionFactor`. As the derivative of the graph gets larger the y-coordinate of close by points on the x-axis become farther way, which eventually will lead to the lines drawn between the points be clearly visible as lines. Although a factor of `precisionFactor = 1` will work fine for most curves.

```java
class SineCurve extends JPanel {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setContentPane(new SineCurve());
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        });

    }

    private final double precisionFactor = 1;
    private final double axisWidth = Math.PI * 4;
    private final double axisHeight = 3;
    private final double axisShiftX = -axisWidth / 2;
    private final double axisShiftY = -axisHeight / 2;

    public SineCurve() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.drawLine(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height);

        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.drawLine(0, height / 2, width, height / 2);

        double precision = precisionFactor * width;
        double stepSize = width / precision;

        double xCurrent = 0;
        double yCurrent = axisToScreen(Math.sin(-axisWidth / 2), height, axisHeight, axisShiftY);

        Path2D path = new Path2D.Double(Path2D.WIND_EVEN_ODD, (int) (width / stepSize));
        path.moveTo(xCurrent, yCurrent);

        while (xCurrent <= width) {
            xCurrent += stepSize;

            double xInAxisSpace = screenToAxis(xCurrent, width, axisWidth, axisShiftX);
            double yInAxisSpace = Math.sin(xInAxisSpace);
            yCurrent = axisToScreen(yInAxisSpace, height, axisHeight, axisShiftY);
            path.lineTo(xCurrent, yCurrent);
        }

        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.draw(path);
    }

    private double screenToAxis(double valueInScreenSpace, double screenSize, double axisSize, double axisShift) {
        return (valueInScreenSpace / screenSize) * axisSize + axisShift;
    }

    private double axisToScreen(double valueInAxisSpace, double screenSize, double axisSize, double axisShift) {
        return screenSize * ((valueInAxisSpace - axisShift) / axisSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added some explanation for `Path2D` and the advantage of using separate screen/axis coordinates.

Comment: But like I said it scales automatically, because of `Main.breite`and `Main.höhe`. With my screen resolution height I can only see 32 Points on x-Axis. But if you got a screen resolution height smaller than 720p you will see that the Points on the x-Axis go down, because it all depends on `Main.höhe`, because one unit is exactly `Main.höhe/20` a twenth of your screen resolution height. So when it is time to calculate, he takes the value `x2,y` multiplies it by the standard unit `Main.höhe`and adds it to the `Main.breite/2` and `Main.höhe/2` (because it is the point  where the y and x-Axis meet)

Comment: So if I use a screen Resolution of 1280x800, you get this: https://imgur.com/a/4qc3FBK

Comment: You are only calculating the width and height of the frame once. What if you want to change the size of the frame? Also as I have noted in my answer you are already doing the same thing.

Comment: Well, you can't. The frame size comes from `private static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    public static double breite = screenSize.getWidth();
    public static double höhe = screenSize.getHeight();`